# How to use Google API (Access Calendar) when user is logged in via Amplify Auth Google SSO in flutter app

Tags: flutter, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-api, aws-amplify

I have to populate Google Calendar with events from a flutter app. To do that I want to use `googleapis`.

The issue is getting a Google Access Token. I understand it is possible to make a custom attribute for user pool and make an AWS Lambda function to populate it with the Google Access Token when a user logs in using `signInWithWebUI()` method but I have no idea how to do that and if it is worth it.

Obviously the easiest option would be to ask user to log in again with `google_sign_in` and get the token from there, but that wouldn't be a good UX.

Is there any other option I have missed?

Tried to get access token directly from Auth using `fetchAuthSession()` method, but that returns AWS access token not google access token.

I have added custom attribute to user pool for google access token, but I have no idea how to write lambda function to actually populate that with the token and if it is even possible.